# Member "push" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

**Issue**
There seems to be some issue with this line here `family.People.push(people[x]);`

I keep getting `Member "push" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup` when I try to compile with brownie.

**What have I tried**
I saw a few SO posts with similar exceptions but it was related to type casting. I did try to cast my incoming array to its type but it just resulted in more exceptions.

**Code**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract Person{
    string public FirstName;
    string public LastName;
}

contract Family{
    Person[] public People;
}

contract FamilyManager{
    Family[] Families;

    function AddFamily(Person[] memory people) public {
        Family family = new Family();
        for(uint x; x < people.length; x++){
            family.People.push(people[x]);
        }
        Families.push(family);
    }

    function GetFamilies() public view returns (Family[] memory){
        return Families;
    }
}
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here or link to an article that can lead to an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is related to `access modifiers`. Using the `public` modifier for your array only generates the `getter` function for it and not the `setter`.
As a result, you cannot directly push to an array from another contract. I created a `public` function to add elements to the array as follows:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract Person{
    string public FirstName;
    string public LastName;
}

contract Family{
    Person[] public People;

    function addPerson(Person person) public {
        People.push(person);
    }
}

contract FamilyManager{
    Family[] Families;

    function AddFamily(Person[] memory people) public {
        Family family = new Family();
        for(uint x; x < people.length; x++) {
            family.addPerson(people[x]);
        }
        Families.push(family);
    }

    function GetFamilies() public view returns (Family[] memory){
        return Families;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes I didn't realize it was a property with only a getter and not just a variable that could be directly set. This fixed it. Thanks